# Is it possible to transfer Bitcoin from one wallet to another wallet?

Tags: sending

For example, if I buy bitcoin from Blockchain, can I transfer it to Coinbase?

And will there be a transfer fee involved or is it free?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. You bitcoins are not stored in the the wallet which may be a web wallet, hardware wallet or paper wallet. They are stored on the bitcoin network (the blockchain). The wallet is just a reference.

You can transfer bitcoins from any wallet to any other wallet.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only addressed the first part of the question. You can transfer from any wallet to any wallet. The second part is below.

The fee is for your transaction to be included in the next block which has limited space. While technically, you can forego the fee and potentially have your transaction go through, it will likely take an extremely long time to happen if you do this.

I suggest looking at https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ to see what an appropriate fee is to move your funds around.